# Ruby on Rails: Retrieve id of selection made in f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got a predefined selection list and i want to get the id of the selected item in the list.

My selection list is as  follows:

Type: <%= f.select(:SUB_TYPE, [['Type1', 't1'],
                                   ['Type2', 't2'],
                                   ['Type3', 't3']
                                  ],{ :prompt => "Select the Type"},
                                  {:onChange => "ShowTypeForm(this.value)"}
                                ) %>

What i want to know is how to retrieve the id of the selection made, in ruby on rails

Many many thanks

Comment: you want the selection id of the select in rails or in js?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the id of the selection made." Are you talking about the id of a DOM element or the id of a Rails object?

Comment: Lets's say am selecting 'Type3' in the drop down, i want to be able to get the id 't3' associated with 'Type3' and store it in a session variable in RoR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is part of a form it will be sent through using the name provided. In this case it looks to be a parameter you've named `SUB_TYPE` but to be sure check your development logs when submitting. The `params` hash is listed there for each request.

As you have this operating on a form, the form will have an object that is being updated, so the parameters are grouped around that.

It may be as easy as:

```
# :example refers to the object the form was built around
selection_id = params[:example][:SUB_TYPE]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that i want to be able to store the currently selected option in a session variable before submitting the form.

Comment: There is a link on my page which redirects the user to another page where he can select something else. When the user comes back to the original form, the selected value in the dropdown list is lost. So i was thinking of retaining that value in a session before user navigates to another page

Comment: I want to do <%= session[:assayForm] = **(this.value)** %> , where (this.value) represents the current selection made before submitting form. But i have no idea how to replace 'this.value' with some code in ruby which retrieves the current selection

Comment: Also, i would like to know how to retain the value in the above f.select when the page is refreshed

Comment: @Kum your request doesn't make any sense. The Rails server doesn't have any idea what you're doing with the form until you submit it. When you do submit it, simply use `params` -- it's what its there for.

Comment: @Kum why do you need the user to leave the page to select something? I would question that design first of all. The web is stateless, and you can't preserve the form state on the backend without a POST.